# Given a list of real numbers and a target value V, find a contiguous block (of any length) whose sum is as close to V as possible

Tags: arrays

Given a list of real numbers and a target value V, find a contiguous block (of any length) whose sum is as close to V as possible.

Brute force is O(n^2) by computing all subarrays' sum then check min_diff between any sum and the target value. how can I come up with O(n) solution?
I think about sliding window but I think I can not come up with a solution to shrink the sliding window. also, I think about maxSum contiguous problem approach (if diff starts to increase I should reset the result and start new subarray sum ) but I don't think it works.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Is the list of real numbers sorted, or random order? Is the interval between numbers constant (i.e., integers 2 units apart, 12, 14, 16 etc.).  Anyway, if they are sorted, you can divide V by 2, find the sum of the two numbers nearest that value, now divide by 3 and sum the 3 numbers closest and keep or discard based on it being a closer sum. Then divide V by 4, etc.  If unsorted, create a new array comprised of the sum of each pair (1st and 2nd, 2nd and 3rd) and another array for the triples, and combos of 4, etc. and then search each such "sum" arrays for the nearest value.  Hth,

Comment: Your puzzle seems to come from here https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/ which doesn't list an O(n) solution. O(n log n)  is the best listed